# HTTP Response timeout issue in mule

Tags: http, mule, mmc, response-time, api-gateway

I am facing one issue with Http response timeout in one of my API which is deployed into API Gateway in MMC. The response timeout of that API is 30 sec and we are referring this timeout value from a property file.

Now my new requirement is to increase that response timeout value to 10 min. So I have increased it in property file to 10 min so that my API will take that value.

**Issue:** When I tested it on my local machine with increasing timeout value it is getting success but the same is throwing an error message in MMC within 32sec. I guess something is overriding this timeout value in MMC.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue in MMC.

*NOTE: My API has linked to gateway domain.*

Answer (score 0):

1.Please cross check if your application is referring to the same property file as in local environment or any other property file has been created inside MMC.

2.You can try using a global configuration Timeout in this way:

Replace defaultTransactiontimeout with the value from properties file.

Comment: I already checked that first point, i am referring to same file in both local and MMC. Can you please tell me how to configure 2nd one?

Comment: Specify the below:<configuration defaultTransactionTimeout="30000"
         defaultResponseTimeout="30000" doc:name="Configuration">
         <default-threading-profile
             poolExhaustedAction="RUN" />
     </configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Please try below in your configuration file(API xml)

**defaultTransactionTimeout="time in mili seconds"**

```
<configuration defaultTransactionTimeout="600000">
 // your other configurations,if any 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions. My issue got resolved and it is actually at network level configurations not at code level.

Comment: Can you please throw more light.. may be it could prove helpful to someone like us

Answer (score 0):

You may also have to make sure there are no firewall issues with the server you are trying to access through the http request. You may have to use proxy if direct access to the server is not available.